# Updating Apollo Cache Without Variables

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Originally, I make a GraphQL call as follows:

```js
query getItems($filter_ids: [Int!], $filter: item_records_bool_exp) {
 items(order_by: { negative: asc, parent: asc }, where: { level: { _in: [2, 3] } }) {
  i18n {
   value
  }
  id
  parent
  negative
 }
 filters(where: { category: { _eq: "PLAN" } }) {
  id
  value
 }
}
```

Now, when I insert a new item, I update the cache using `update` function in the mutation options, and I'm supposed to use `readQuery`/`readFragment` and `writeQuery`/`writeFragment` to interact with the Apollo Cache as described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/caching/cache-interaction/).

My question is, my `readQuery` calls always fail if I do not provide the exact same variables that I had previous provided to the original GraphQL query. Is there a way around this? In other words, can I just read objects from the cache by their ID irrespective of the original query that was used to fetch these objects?